# Статус пользователя на сайте

Tags: php, javascript

Как лучше сделать проверку пользователя на сайте, через куки или через запись времени после авторизации?

И каким образом можно отслеживать действия пользователя на сайте?

Comment: проверку чего ? какие действия ?

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется лучше записывать в бд действия пользователя, например есть поле ид и последнее совершённое действие с данными 1/0 (1 совершил действие и 0 не совершил действие) и + время если пользователь совершил действие.
Если пользователь совершил действие то данные обновятся и и обновится действие и на пример условие которое каждые 15 минут будет проверять есть ли где 0 в таблице. Минус такого подхода запросов к бд много будет. Плюсы прост понятен в написании трудно обмануть вас если вам важно кто совершал действия

Comment: как определять эти самые действия???

Comment: зависит на чем ты пишешь

Comment: тут уже готовый код писать надо, поставил ли пользователь лайк, отправил сообщение, много что сюда можно написать

Comment: пишу на пхп, я не нашел нормального мануала в сети, номального, т.е. который может раскрыть тему максимально, я сколько информации не встречал, так и не видел примеров или объяснений по поводу определения действий пользователя на сайте. помогите понять или приведите хотя бы примеров пару чтоб понять откуда начинать копать

Comment: на данный момент я сделал просто проверку каждые 5 минут и обновление времени пользователя с помощью ajax, но как мне кажется и как я понимаю это не лучший подход оссобенно когда сайт расчитывается на тысячную аудиторию

Comment: web socet php тебе в помощь